# Linear Programming fmincon. Why won't the code work?

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I want to find a maximum value using this function:

```
Function f = myfun(a)
    a = {'a1';'a2';'a3';'a4'};
    x = rand(4,5);
    S = -x.*a; 
    SS = sum(S); 
    [~,ix] = sort(SS); 
    R = rand(1,5)
    SR = R(ix); 
    f = sum(SR(1:10));
    Aeq=ones(4,1); 
    beq=1;  
    a0=[.25 .25 .25 .25]';  
    [a,f] = fmincon(@myfun,a0,[],[],Aeq,beq);    
end
```

The code throws an error:

> error: Undefined function or method 'mtimes' for input arguments of type 'cell'

Do you know why?

Comment: In what way does this not work ?

Comment: for example, it asks me to define 'a'

Comment: error: Undefined function or method 'mtimes' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Answer (score 1):

As shown, your function is not valid Matlab.  The use of 'F' in 'Function' rather than 'f' will raise a warning, but the presence of 'end' at the end of the function definition is a syntax error.  Correct those errors, then run the function in Debug mode.  Your next problem is that

```
S = -x.*a;
```

is not defined where the rhs ('a' in this case) is a cell array, which your earlier declaration made it.  It's also very strange that you expect (in the first line) 'a' to be an argument to the function, but in l2 define it to be a cell array containing 4 strings.

Comment: That sums things up nicely, though even if he does make sure a is a vector, instead of a cell array, that line will still have an dimension error.  To do what (I think)he wants it to do, it should be S = bsxfun(@times, -x, a)

Comment: How can I define 'a'? S is actually calculated like this: s1 = -x(1,:)*a1; s2 = -x(2,:)*a2.....s4 = -x(4,:)*a4.

Comment: @user1205030: I fear that you are trying to run before you can walk.  I suggest that you (a) write a sequence of commands into the Matlab command window until they do what you want then (b) read the beginning documentation on how to write functions, then (c) edit the sequence of commands into a valid function definition.

Comment: @user1205030: good luck in what seems to be a very difficult situation for you.

Comment: @High Performance Mark. 'function ... end' is valid Matlab syntax. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/function.html : "You can terminate any type of function with an end statement, but doing so is not required..."

Comment: @Kavka: yes, you're right, the syntax error arising from the 'end' is generated otherwise.